# Real time messaging application

Tags: ios, objective-c, parsing, messaging

I am curious to know the advantages between using parse or a custom xmpp server. I am curious if parse has the capability of being used for creating a real time chat application, because I have never used parse for that use. Or would it be easier and better to use a custom xmpp server to handle messages. I am also curious if parse would be able to completely delete data off the server because that is what my application requires. As background info I have already started the project with parse, but I could switch over to another option if it is necessary.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my experience with working with Parse, I don't believe that it's the correct solution for your needs.

You may get things up and running at first, but as you try to scale your application, you're going to need to ramp up your servers (and cost!) greatly to handle so many requests. Parse's pricing is based on your requests count for the month. Imagine how many requests you expect one user to make in a month. Now times that by 1000.... Not very scalable, huh?

Now I don't know much about xmpp servers, but I've heard from some colleagues that applications like WhatsApp are using Erlang and TCP servers (just like Call of Duty) to handle message requests. In fact, here's an article that talks about the logistics of WhatsApps technology https://www.erlang-solutions.com/about/news/erlang-powered-whatsapp-exceeds-200-million-monthly-users

Best of luck!

Comment: It should be pointed out that the premiere XMPP server, ejabberd, is itself written in Erlang. XMPP may or may not be what OP wants, but like a RESTful HTTP API, it can be used to implement a specific application state model. Unlike HTTP, it's stateful, so your connection is always available (for good or bad). Ejabberd XMPP components can be written in *any* language that has a library that supports that feature of XMPP -- not just Erlang. But hey -- it's also a great excuse to learn a fantastic language. Writing your own app protocol over TCP is okay, too, but more work in the long run, IMHO.

Comment: Nice comment. Led me to learn more about XMPP :)

Comment: Thank you so much! It looks like i will be moving away from parse, and even though it may take some more time, but will achieve a higher end product I will look into using Erlang. This was very helpful